# Need to create the signature using public key and body of soap message

Tags: java, web-services, ws-security

I have a certificate (.cer file) and its public key. I need to create a signature using this key and body of soap message and also need to add this generated signature in header part of soap message. like

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-3">
<ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
<ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="SOAP-ENV"/>
</ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#dsa-sha1"/>
<ds:Reference URI="#id-2"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
<ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList=""/>
</ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>EjzOmzoHrDq0U17/15G4ROWuLBM=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>jisobLxDo3AKD+CFgamH/7vuLkVNqZN18Xh65ZlajNODlvh2wPJEyg==</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-0E3A8F2C1EE953718314449294173862">
<wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-0E3A8F2C1EE953718314449294173883">
<ds:X509Data<ds:X509IssuerSerial><ds:X509IssuerName>CN=Sujit Arungundram,OU=NB,O=SFG,L=Chicago,ST=IL,C=US
</ds:X509IssuerName><ds:X509SerialNumber>1790402324</ds:X509SerialNumber></ds:X509IssuerSerial></ds:X509Data>
</wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-1"><wsu:Created>2015-10-15T17:16:57.309Z</wsu:Created>
<wsu:Expires>2015-10-15T17:21:57.309Z</wsu:Expires></wsu:Timestamp>
</wsse:Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-2"><ns2:TransactionRequest xmlns="http://schema.ACORD.csc.com/Standard/Life/2" xmlns:ns2="http://com/sfg/spcltymkts/webservices/csctxlife">
    Body content
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Basically i need to add `<wsse:Security>` inside header part.

Answer (score 1):

You need your private key to sign your soap request with.
Your public key is for other parties to use to encrypt/decrypt messages to/from you.

[Here](https://sites.google.com/site/ddmwsst/ws-security-impl#TOC-Create-Crypto-Properties-File) is a link you might find useful.

Comment: thanks for the reply.actually we are creating the soap message manually, can't configure the interceptor and all.